# Clear Expanation for ServletContext context=getServletContext();

Tags: java, servlets

```
ServletContext context=getServletContext();
```

Here ServletContext is the Interface.

Context is the type of ServletContext

`getServletContext` is a method in `ServletContext` Interface returning the information about the Servlet.

Here my Question is we are creating an context object for interface.How can we create an object for interface?

If not we are creating the object for ServletContect what exactly we are doing here
what is the mapping between ServletContext and getServletContext()?

Please explain step by step thanks in advance?

Comment: No, `getServletContext` is a method in the `ServletRequest` interface. It feels like actually your question is more about interfaces in general than servlets in particular. I suggest you read a Java tutorial around interfaces before you go any further with servlets.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  For a start there is no method `getServletContext()` in the `ServletContext` interface (see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html).  Could you clarify what you're after?

Comment: @JonSkeet: or possibly in `ServletConfig`...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is `How can we create an object for interface?` 
`Answer is :` We cannot create an object of interface(any interface) but we can assign reference of the interface implemented class's object (This is valid and gives polymorphism and inheritance in OOPs)
I would suggest to read **Head First Core Java** to better understand all these things. 
We cannot invoke **`new`** keyword after interface and ends with semicolon Ex.

```
ServletContext context = new ServletContext(); //invalid. cannot end with semicolon
```

But after several reading you will find a construct/syntax like

```
ServletContext context = new ServletContext() {    // see semicolon absent after ()

// and all methods here with some definition

};
```

This is anonymous class which is implementing ServletContext interface.

if you see construct like

```
Thread t = new Thread() {  //semicolon is absent after () bracket

};
```

means it is anonymous class which is extending class Thread.

Answer (score 0):

`getServletContext` is not method of [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) interface. It is the method of [ServletConfig](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html) interface which [GenericServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html) is implementing and due to this it is available in [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) which is extending [GenericServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html). [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) might be implemented by the Web servers and they might be returning object of that class in [GenericServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html).

Hope this explanation helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is how to create object from interface.

Answer is Can't.

But we can use interface name then we can assign a reference of interface to class object.

(it means we can create Anounymous class(Inside the object)).

for more details read javatpoint interface lesson.